# What to test in a simple DRF API?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

So, I'm not a test expert and sometimes, when using packages like DRF, I think what should I test on the code...

If I write custom functions for some endpoints, I understand I should test this because I've written this code and there are no tests for this... But the DRF codebase is pretty tested.

But if I'm writing a simple API that only extends ModelSerializer and ModelViewSet what should I be testing?

The keys in the JSON serialized?
The relations?

What should I be testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your ModelSerializer, Check the request payload against your expected Model fields.

Testing your ModelViewSet, Check the response HTTP_Status_Code against the expected Status codes for your viewsets. You can also test for your response data.

A good resource - https://realpython.com/test-driven-development-of-a-django-restful-api/

Comment: Thank you!
I did some serializer tests like checking if the validations are working and stuff like this and now i'm testing the viewsets... But sometimes I think I'm testing stuff that the DRF did test

Comment: As the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#validation-in-rest-framework) say, 
_When you're using `ModelSerializer `all of the validation is handled automatically for you. If you want to drop down to using `Serializer` classes instead, then you need to define the validation rules explicitly._

Defining the rules explicitly would require you to test them for their behavior. 

In cases, when you are [overriding](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage) your Serializer behavior, typically you test the behavior.

Comment: Hmm ok. I did override a serializer method and tested it, this is what I think I should be testing, bcs all the other stuff is tested by drf

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're only using automated features and added absolutely no customization on your serializer and viewset, and it's obvious to you that this part of the code works smoothly, you still need to write tests.

Code tends to get large, and some other person might be extending your code, or you might go back to your code a few months later and not remember how your implementation was.  Knowing that tests are passing will inform other people (or yourself in the distant future) that you're code is working without having to read it and dive into the implementation details, which makes your code reliable.

The person using your API might be using it at a service and not even be interested in what framework or language you used for implementation, but only wants to be sure that the features he/she requires work properly. How can we ensure this? One way is to write tests and pass them.

That's why it's very important to write complete and reliable tests so people can safely use or extend your code knowing that the tests are passing and everything is OK.